# NVD3.js using one axis for lineplusbar

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm trying to do a comparison of Actual vs. Required using a lineplusbar chart. However, I'm having trouble getting it to look exactly how I want. Is there a way to have both lines use a single axis?

Code: https://github.com/tvinci/webs/blob/gh-pages/lineplusbar.html

Example: http://tvinci.github.io/webs/lineplusbar.html

Code from page:

```
  nv.addGraph(function() {
     //var testdata = exampleData();
     var chart = nv.models.linePlusBarChart()
           .margin({top: 30, right: 60, bottom: 50, left: 70})
           //if this is commented out, the graph does not display properly
           .x(function(d,i) { return i });
     //this is the cheat I use to show the correct X axis
     //chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.format(',f')(d+1)+"x" });
     chart.y1Axis.tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));
     chart.y2Axis.tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));

     //forces the chart to start at 0
     // if you set this to [0,100] and your data's domain is -10 to 110, the domain will be [-10,110]
     chart.lines.forceY([0]);

     d3.select('#chart svg').datum(eval("overview_data")).transition().duration(500).call(chart);
      d3.selectAll("rect.nv-bar").style("fill", function(d, i){return i > 50 ? "red":"blue";});
     nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
```

Data:

```
var overview_data=[
     { "key" : "Achieved" , "bar": true,"values" : [ [ "1x" , 30] , [ "2x" , 70] , [ "3x" , 200] ]} ,
     { "key" : "Required" , "values" : [ [ "1x" , 50] , [ "2x" , 100] , [ "3x" , 150] ]}
    ].map(function(series) {series.values = series.values.map(function(d) { return {x: d[0], y: d[1] } });return series;});
```

});

Comment: Could you perhaps update your answer with the relevant code?